# How to replace a special character from a file name in a document in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I am trying to run a PowerShell script through a couple of documents in a folder and replace any documents that may contain some special characters mainly $,#. But I would like to do them both at a time.

```
$files1 | ForEach-Object {Rename-Item $_ ($_.FullName -replace "#", "")}
```

At the moment I'm getting the error below

> Rename-Item : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name '@{FullName=F' does not exist.At line:2 char:3 +   Rename-Item $_ ($_.FullName -replace "#", "")

The Output from the files1 variable is this

```
FullName       : F:\baggy\17_10_27 may waiver - dondeal - EPT 2337 jonney - CLOSE OUT #025-17.msg
ParentFolder   : F:\baggy\
FullPathLength : 108
Extension      : msg
Name           : 17_10_27 may waiver - dondeal - EPT 2337 jonney - CLOSE OUT #025-17.msg
Length         : 121344
LastWriteTime  : 10/27/2017 1:43:02 PM
 
FullName       : F:\baggy\17_10_27 crickey waivers for drum skyline un-cement - #068-17 rewax RX - resent to OOE.msg
ParentFolder   : F:\baggy\
FullPathLength : 106
Extension      : msg
Name           : 17_10_27 crickey waivers for drum skyline un-cement - #068-17 rewax RX - resent to OOE.msg
Length         : 386560
LastWriteTime  : 10/27/2017 4:16:23 PM
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$files1 | ForEach-Object {Rename-Item $_.FullName ($_.FullName -replace "#", "")}
```

If you're not moving the files, however, I'd recommend:

```
$files1 | ForEach-Object {Rename-Item $_.FullName ($_.Name -replace "#", "")}
```

Comment: thank you, both answers worked for me. one final question, is there a way to include sub-folders when replacing the characters? i tried to used '-recurse' but i get this error `"Rename-Item : Source and destination path must be different."`

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path X:\path-you-want | Rename-Item {$_.FullName -replace '#' -replace '$'}
```